# Curl PHP авторизация на сайте не проходит

Tags: php, curl

Необходимо написать авторизацию через Curl на php, но возникла одна проблема. Сайт каким-то образом, кроме данных логина и пароля ещё должен получить параметр `checkFormLogin` с уникальным ключом. Обычно такие данные находятся в той же форме с полями, только в скрытом варианте. А этот сайт хранит его не известно где и не понятно как его получить www.deezer.com/login
В curl настроено `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` и `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` но толку мало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже на защиту от авторизации в обход web-интерфейса. Реализовано в js скорее всего

Comment: @НикитаУмнов я тоже так думаю, но может и временная сессия. Если так, то получается, никак не пройти?

Comment: тут нужно разобраться. Проанализируйте js на сайте, в частности, фрагмент, отвечающий за отправку формы. Возможно, удастся что-то найти. А https://developers.deezer.com изучали? Кажется, у них есть API

Comment: @НикитаУмнов спасибо, это решило проблему, правда с темой вопроса не совсем связано, поэтому не знаю как поступить в данном случае.